# Extract GroupButton Value

Tags: java, radio-button

I am having problem with fetching the value of the radiobutton. I tried `payment.getSelection()` and `payment.getElements()` but it doesn't give me the value.Do you guys have any other way to fetch the value? Thanks

```
final ButtonGroup payment = new ButtonGroup();
payment.add(visaBtn);
payment.add(mastercardBtn);
payment.add(amexBtn);
payment.add(noneBtn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isSelected` method will tell you if the button is selected. The `getText` method will give you the text value of the button. Do either of these help you?

If you're looking for which of the buttons in the group is selected, just loop through the buttons in the group calling `isSelected` on each of them.

Comment: Sorry,im new here.Can you show some sample of how to implement it. I tried isSelected() method but still not working

Comment: Its ok i manage to get it after further research of isSelected,Thank you!!!

My code is this:

if(visaBtn.isSelected()){
       creditCardType = "VISA";
      }